# simple PHP page not working as expected

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to get to the point where I would have a login page and a registration page using the same php controller file. When site.com/?login is entered then the login page is shown (this is done) then when the user submits the login page just for now I want it to display 'access granted/denied'. The same goes for the registration page (site.com/?registeration goes to registration page and submission prints out whether it was successful or not). I am running into a problem in which when either page is submitted it does not show the output I am expecting.

```
<?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'includes/db_connection.php';

/*********************Registration page code***************************/
if (isset($_GET['register']))
{
    $action = 'register_form';
    include 'register.html.php';
    exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'register_form') {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['username']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);

    $output = 'Username: ' . $username . ' Email: ' . $email . ' Password: ' . $password;

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO user (username,email,password) VALUES
            ("'. $username .'","'. $email .'","'. $password .'")';

    if (!mysqli_query($connection, $sql))
    {
        $error = 'Error registering user: ' . mysqli_error($connection);
        include 'output.html.php';
        exit();
    }

    include 'output.html.php';
    exit();
}
/*************************************************************************/

if (isset($_GET['login']))
{
    $action = 'login_form';
    include 'login.html.php';
    exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'login_form' )
{
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);

    $output = 'Username: ' . $username . ' Password: ' . $password;

    $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE username="'.$username.'" AND password="'.$password.'"';
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    if (!$result)
    {
        $error = 'Error seeing if user exists in the DB.';
        include 'output.html.php';
        exit();
    }   

    $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($num > 0) {
        $output .= '\nAccess Granted!';
    } else {
        $output .= '\nAccess Denied! Please register first...';
    }

    include 'output.html.php';
    exit();
}

$output = 'Database connection established.<br/>Server root: ' . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include 'output.html.php';
?>
```

The code below is my registration page (the login page is very similar):

```
<?php include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .
        '/includes/helpers.inc.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Registration</title>
        <!--link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/-->
    </head>
    <body>  
        <div id="content">
            <form id="registration_form" method="POST" action="?<?php htmlout($action); ?>">

                <label for="username-id">Username:</label>
                <input id="username-id" type="text" name="username" autofocus="autofocus" /><br/><br/>

                <label for="email-id">Email:</label>
                <input id="email-id" type="email" name="email" /><br/><br/>

                <label for="password1-id">Password:</label>
                <input id="password1-id" class="text-input" type="password" name="password" /><br/><br/>

                <label for="password2-id">Retype Password:</label>
                <input id="password2-id" class="text-input" type="password" name="password_repeat" /><br/><br/>

                <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The output.html.php page is just a simple page that echo's $output and $error.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? I am pretty new to PHP most of this code has followed the book Build Your Own Database Driven Web Site Using PHP & MySQL.

Comment: `it does not show the output I am expecting` What does it show and what you expect it to show?

Comment: Perhaps `output.html.php` should also echo out `$error`...

Comment: @u_mulder it shows 'Database connection established.
Server root: C:/wamp/www/' basically what is at the bottom of the controller. And if I am logging in I am expecting it to show acces granted or access denied

Comment: @Marc_B it does (sorry forgot to mention it) ... no errors though

Comment: You're reassigning `$output` in the end of script. Is that correct?

Comment: @u_mulder I was under the misunderstanding that that wouldn't run unless none of the conditional statements were entered (guess it's not the case) but not after commenting that out. I have nothing for output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the `action` target for your submission forms? If it contains a query string, your code will not work like you want it to:

```
<form method="post" action="?login">...</form>
```

This is because PHP will always parse the **query string** (everything in the URL following `?`), even if the request actually uses the `POST` verb.

Hence, **you cannot rely on `$_GET` to be empty in a `POST` request**.
(You do this with `if(isset($_GET['login']))`)

You can, however, use another superglobal's field to get the request method:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // Form has been submitted
} else {
    // Not a POST request, proabably GET
}
```

Documentation can be found on [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

---

**Edit 1**

Besides, *nick bonnet*'s answer also applies here.
You cannot access the form element's `action` attribute (nor any other attribute) through `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

Those only contain the parsed query string (`$_GET`) and - for `POST` request - the parsed request body (`$_POST`; which is built by the browser using `name` and `value` attributes of a `form`'s children)

---

**Edit 2**

A suggestion how I would structure this "application" (keeping the `?xy` URL format):

```
<?php

/* DB connection and bootstrapping code goes here */

if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
    if('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
        // FORM HAS BEEN SUBMITTED,
        // process user input (login credentials) and display a message
    } else {
        // Assume GET or HEAD,
        // display login form
    }
}
elseif (isset($_GET['registration'])) {
    if('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
        // FORM HAS BEEN SUBMITTED,
        // process user input (registration data) and display a message
    } else {
        // Assume GET or HEAD,
        // display registration form
    }
}
else {
    // No page found
    include '404.html.php';
}

?>
```

The form and form submission now share the same URL (`?login` or `?registration`) and are distinguished by the request method (`GET` for form, `POST` for subission).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to apply what you are saying to fix my problem sorry. If you could explain some more or reword (be very clear for a beginning) that'd help very much, thank you.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean now. I like this, less work and highly maintainable. Good work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are checking for

```
   and $_POST['action'] == 'register_form')
```

but actually with

```
    <form id="registration_form" method="POST" action="?<?php htmlout($action); ?>">
```

you are sending it a

```
    $_GET['action']
```

You need to add

```
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="register_form" />
```

or change condition to

```
   and isset($_GET['register_form'])
```

Comment: Quick note: `method="POST"`, not `"GET"`

Comment: Read more closely please! `method="POST"`

Comment: @Izkata Everything you put into action="" of a form is submitted as GET no matter the method, to submit a $_POST field you have to have an <input>.

Comment: what should I do with the action attribute in the form then? get rid of it or what to have in it if it does not matter in my case?

Comment: Ah, right.  But regardless, unless I missed something else as well, it wasn't sending that anyway - the querystring would be `?register_form`, not `?action=register_form`, right?

Comment: @nickbonnet `action` is the page to post the form to

Comment: I've fixed my answer regarding the check of $_GET. You should not use that and put a hidden input with action, since combining both POST and GET can be quite confusing and will be additional source of errors.

Comment: SO I added the hidden attribute ... removed the $action variable from the php controller (besides the checking) and the new action attribute of the form is action="?". Now it works! Everything seem okay with what I just said?

Comment: If you've added the <input type="hidden" name="action" value="register_form"/> then no changes to php script were required.